# Simple C++ Program with Multidimensional Array Errors?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

When running the following code, I am attempting to update a Tic Tac Toe game board.
When you type in 3 as a column, it sets 2 X's or O's in the game board.

**Here is an example of the output**

```
*  *  *
*  *  *
*  *  *

X: Select a Row: 1
X: Select a Col: 3
*  *  X
X  *  *
*  *  *
```

**Here is the desired output**

```
*  *  *
*  *  *
*  *  *

X: Select a Row: 1
X: Select a Col: 3
*  *  X
*  *  *
*  *  *
```

**Here is the code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int rowSelect = 0;
    int colSelect = 0;
    char turn = 'X';
    char rowcol[2][2];

    for(int i=0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            rowcol[i][j] = '*';
        }
    }

    for(int i=0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            cout << rowcol[i][j] << "  ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;

    while (true)
    {

        cout << turn << ": Select a Row: ";
        cin >> rowSelect;
        while (rowSelect < 1 || rowSelect > 3)
        {
            cout << "I cannot accept that value, try again!" << endl;
            cout << endl;
            cout << turn << ": Select a Row: ";
            cin >> rowSelect;
        }

    cout << turn << ": Select a Col: ";
    cin >> colSelect;
    while (colSelect < 1 || colSelect > 3)
    {
        cout << "I cannot accept that value, try again!" << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << turn << ": Select a Col: " << endl;
        cin >> colSelect;
    }

    rowcol[rowSelect-1][colSelect-1] = turn;

    if (turn == 'X')
    {
        turn = 'O';
    }
    else
    {
        turn = 'X';
    }

        for(int i=0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                cout << rowcol[i][j] << "  ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }

    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks!

-Mike

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the array. Although arrays are accessed using zero based indices, the definition requires the actual number of elements for which to reserve space.

You defined rowcol as:

```
char rowcol[2][2];  // This defines a 2 x 2 array
```

You should have defined rowcol as:

```
 char rowcol[3][3];  // This defines a 3 x 3 array
```

Hope this helps!

Keith

Answer (score 3):

Your rowcol array needs to be 3x3:

```
char rowcol[3][3];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char rowcol[2][2];
```

In all the cases, `i, j` must iterate only until `< 2` since it is a 2x2 array.

Answer (score 0):

- Your array only holds 2 elements per row, while your loop runs through three rows and three columns. You seem to be confused on how arrays are numbered, an array with 2 elements would be accessed using elements[0] and elements[1], because 0 is the first number in programming(not 1). you need to declare an array of THREE elements, and access them using [0] [1] and [2].

FIX: change to `char Array[3][3];`